# MYSQL -- Getting most popular item based on where condition in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called forumposts(this contains the thread id which is auto incremented), which represents forum threads.I have another table, forumreplies(each reply has a threadid, which refers to the thread id from forumposts).

I would like to display only popular forum threads, basically get threads that have the highest numbers of replies for each forum thread.Is there any way to do it in mySQL?

Comment: Hint: Use `GROUP BY` and `SUM` functions in your `forumreplies` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT ThreadId,
  COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM FORUMREPLIES
GROUP BY ThreadId
ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```

Thanks